# Stream rasberry pi audio to my windows pc

Tags: audio, linux, windows, pi-zero

On my Raspberry Pi Zero I'm using an HDMI to VGA adapter. So I have no audio output for my RPIZ. I'm wondering how hard would it be to stream audio from my RPIZ to my windows 7 PC.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I believe there have been q&a's about that issue before. Did you search the site for those? It furthermore sounds like a weird setup. You intend to run that windows machine every time the Pi operates? If so, could the windows PC not just do the job ;-) It might be worth considering an additional analogue output to simplify things. There is also a Q about that on the zero.

Comment: I have not found anything yet on the topic. I found people wishing to stream audio to the RPi but not the other way around.

Comment: Further to the oddness: It's *really* common for HDMI to VGA adapters to include a 3.5mm analogue audio out socket. If yours doesn't, it may be worth investing in one that does. They're fairly cheap. I've used [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tendak-Gold-Plated-Adapter-Converter-Projector/dp/B00VTJVJ3S?ie=UTF8&redirect=true&ref_=pe_931411_45466481) Tendak ones before, and they work fairly well on HDMI bus power alone.

Comment: If you only want to stream audio, VLC can do that.

If you want to display video on the HDMI/VGA and stream the audio, I imagine that *can* be done with some low-level VLC, but I'm not sure. But really, why don't you pick up a pHat DAC? Very sweet audio output device.

Comment: After dwelling on this for a moment, I realise that there is a *possible* path, depending on how adventurous you are.. On Ubuntu (at least) you can route the audio output from VLC to JACK and from there route to some streaming software (gstreamer?). It *can* be done, but if your aim is video on HDMI and audio on PC, you'll probably experience lag for the streaming audio that could possibly be adjusted by delaying the video in VLC.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably work out a solution which uses ffmpeg rtp to stream the audio in real time (with a small amount of latency) from an alsa audio driver to a different computer. I assume you have some sort of networking going on ... possibly over usb ?

Look for information on ffmpeg (avconv on the pi) "-i alsa" using the real time "rtp://" protocol ... which is basically a UDP streamer. You will want to use an ALSA plugin which allows you to copy the output stream in some way for use as an input stream.

If you want audio input/output through the GPIO header, elinux has a good list of available audio add on solutions :
http://elinux.org/index.php?title=RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound